# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element python click

Tags: python, selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GX1VE.png)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Driver\chrome driver\chromedriver")

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")

trending = driver.find_element_by_class_name("title style-scope ytd-guide-entry-renderer").click()

driver.quit()